# UnwantedTokenException(found=., expected 80) JPA on Spring Web Project

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, jpa

I m seeing this error when I used my readAll method on myService .What can be problem is onyone see this error before I couldn't find any usefull information about it after a wide googling here is my codes

NewsDAO

```
public interface NewsDAO extends GenericDAO<News, Serializable> {
  }
```

NewsDAOImpl

```
public class NewsDAOImpl extends GenericJPADAOImpl<News, Serializable> implements NewsDAO {
```

}

News

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "News")
public class News implements Serializable {...blah blah}
```

The problem appear when I use this method (its a method from my service level)

```
  @Override
public List<Article> articleList() {
    return articleDAO.readAll();
}
```

There is no connection error I m using mysql on a spring project  .Any advice will be great 
Thanks

```
UnwantedTokenException(found=., expected 80) at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:587)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.rangeVariableDeclaration(JPQLParser.java:2249)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.identificationVariableDeclaration(JPQLParser.java:2162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.fromClause(JPQLParser.java:2043)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectStatement(JPQLParser.java:364)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.document(JPQLParser.java:281)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:134)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.buildParseTree(JPQLParser.java:95)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:215)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:190)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:126)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1475)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
at $Proxy42.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.dcat.dao.impl.GenericJPADAOImpl.readAll(GenericJPADAOImpl.java:38)
at com.dcat.ipp.service.impl.AdminServiceImpl.getNewsList(AdminServiceImpl.java:348)
at com.dcat.ipp.service.impl.AdminServiceImpl.getNewsListAsSpot(AdminServiceImpl.java:354)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy48.getNewsListAsSpot(Unknown Source)
at com.dcat.ipp.controller.HomeController.getNewsSpotList(HomeController.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: This has what to do with SQL & mySQL?

Comment: @xQbert Its getting article list from database

Comment: @JMelnik I can insert and update the article anyway data to mysql tables but when I try to read them from database it gives this error.Actually when I try to read as a collection it gives this error.For a single specific article like with the parameter  articleId=3 it works  without this problem

Comment: You get some error but don't quote it or its stack trace. You say SQL is used but don't quote the SQL. I'd start with those two ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `em.createQuery` and a native query with it.

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a From Product")
```

It got solved -  when I used Native query,

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * from tbl_product")
```